# Combining SQL Query Results Into One Table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm trying to combine queries so the results are in one table.

```
SELECT sku.idsku, amaterial.material
FROM sku
INNER JOIN amaterial ON sku.idsku = amaterial.sku_idsku
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Produces:

idsku material 
13 Steel

```
SELECT sku.idsku, amcolor.color
FROM sku
INNER JOIN amcolor ON sku.idsku = amcolor.sku_idsku
```

Produces

idsku color 
13 red 
17 purple

```
SELECT sku.idsku, atype.type
FROM sku
INNER JOIN atype ON sku.idsku = atype.sku_idsku
```

Produces

idsku type 
13 labret 
17 barbell

What I want to create is a table as follows:

idsku material color  type
13    steel     red   labret
17      ----       purple  barbell

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: SELECT sku.idsku, amaterial.material, amcolor.color, atype.type
FROM sku, amaterial, amcolor, atype
WHERE sku.idsku = amaterial.sku_idsku
AND sku.idsku = atype.sku_idsku
AND sku.idsku = amcolor.sku_idsku
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you put all your queries into one?

```
 SELECT sku.idsku, amaterial.material, amcolor.color, atype.type
 FROM sku sku
 INNER JOIN amaterial ON sku.idsku = amaterial.sku_idsku
 INNER JOIN amcolor ON sku.idsku = amcolor.sku_idsku
 INNER JOIN atype ON sku.idsku = atype.sku_idsku
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: The query returns results only on the skuid that doesn't have null values.  For example, since idsku 17 doesn't have a material defined the record doesn't show.

Comment: Busilinks, yes, i've forgotten about join rules